# Adding more condition to an already existing expressi

Tags: vba, ssrs-2012

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder I'd like to add this

```
iif((Fields!FieldID.Value = 530 
        And datediff("d",Parameters!StartDate.Value,Fields!Value4Search)<61 
        And datediff("d",Fields!Value4Search,Parameters!StartDate.Value)>31)
    ,"DarkGreen"
    ,"Red"
    )
```

To the already existing color condition i have on a report :

```
=iif((Fields!FieldTypeId.Value=2) And (Fields!FieldID.Value<>69), 
    iif(DateDiff("d",
            Parameters!StartDate.Value,
            Cdate(FormatDateTime(
                iif(Fields!FieldTypeId.Value=2,
                    Fields!Value4Search.Value,
                    Parameters!StartDate.Value
                    ),
            DateFormat.ShortDate)
            )
        )<0 ,  
    "Red", 
    "LimeGreen"
    ), 
Fields!def_Color.Value
)
```

I tried this but either got an error, or the Fields!Value4Search while Fields!FieldID.Value = 530 turn limegreen if it's not in the interval instead of red.

```
=iif(
    (Fields!FieldID.Value = 530 And
    Fields!Value4Search.Value < DateAdd("d", -61, Parameters!StartDate.Value) And
    Fields!Value4Search.Value > DateAdd("d", 31, Parameters!StartDate.Value)),
    "Red",
        iif(
            Fields!FieldTypeId.Value = 2 And
            Fields!FieldID.Value <> 69,
            iif(
                DateDiff(
                    "d",
                    Parameters!StartDate.Value,
                    Cdate(
                        FormatDateTime(
                            iif(
                                Fields!FieldTypeId.Value = 2,
                                Fields!Value4Search.Value,
                                Parameters!StartDate.Value
                            ),
                            DateFormat.ShortDate
                        )
                    )
                ) < 0,
                "Red",
                "LimeGreen"
            ),
            Fields!def_Color.Value
        )
    )
```

But turn lime when not in interval

```
IIf(Fields!FieldTypeId.Value = 2 AND 
    (Fields!FieldID.Value = 530 And 
    datediff("d",Parameters!StartDate.Value,Fields!Value4Search)<61 And
    datediff("d",Fields!Value4Search,Parameters!StartDate.Value)>31),
    "DarkGreen",
    IIF(Fields!FieldTypeId.Value = 2 And Fields!FieldID.Value <> 69,
        IIf(DateDiff("d",
                    Parameters!StartDate.Value,
                    CDate(FormatDateTime(
                        IIf(Fields!FieldTypeId.Value = 2,
                            Fields!Value4Search.Value,
                            Parameters!StartDate.Value
                            ),
                        DateFormat.ShortDate
                        )
                    )
            ) < 0,
        "Red",
        "LimeGreen"
        ),
        IIF(Fields!FieldTypeId.Value = 2 AND (Fields!FieldID.Value = 530 And 
            datediff("d",Parameters!StartDate.Value,Fields!Value4Search)>61 And
            datediff("d",Fields!Value4Search,Parameters!StartDate.Value)<31),
        "RED",
        Fields!def_Color.Value
        )
    )
)
```

But got an error when clicking ok in the expression window

Also tried but everything was in black (def_color in the sql request)

```
=iif(
    (Fields!FieldTypeId.Value=2) And (Fields!FieldID.Value<>69),
    iif(
        (Fields!FieldID.Value = 530 And 
        datediff("d",Parameters!StartDate.Value,Fields!Value4Search)<61 And
        datediff("d",Fields!Value4Search,Parameters!StartDate.Value)>31),
        "DarkGreen",
        iif(
            DateDiff("d",Parameters!StartDate.Value,Cdate(FormatDateTime(
                iif(Fields!FieldTypeId.Value=2,
                    Fields!Value4Search.Value,
                    Parameters!StartDate.Value
                ),
                DateFormat.ShortDate
            )))<0,
            "Red",
            "LimeGreen"
        )
    ),
    Fields!def_Color.Value
)
```

Comment: You might need to explain, in English, what you are trying to do, give some samples of data and expected results, however, the first thing I noticed is that when you are doing the check for a date range, your expression will return negative numbers if the parameter is later than the Value4Search field. Try putting the parameter 1st (like your <61 comparison) in both parts. It's also worth adding extra test columns with each part of your expression in so you can see what is being returned from each part.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Iif Statment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/iif-function

Although its true that the Iif(Condition, TrueValue, FalseValue) can be nested, I would say its bad practice and its better to use standard nested if then else statments. Also, the code is much more readable and understandable 5, 10 or 20 years later.

I would only use an Iif statment when I already know that if a condition is true I want value XYZ returned and if its false then I want ABC returned.

If there is a next if statement to follow then I would switch the Iif statement for a standard if then else.

Now, I couldn't quite follow exactly what it is you were attemting to do but I gathered the following:

Your new code block

1. If the record.fieldid value = 530
   and date difference is within 61 days before
   and upto 31 days later than the date in parameters.startdate
   then make the text DarkGreen otherwise make it red.

Your existing code block
And you wish to add this to your existing block of code, which does the following:

1. If the record.fieldtypeid = 2
   we will use the record.value4search date value as the test date
   otherwise;
   we will use the parameters.startdate value as the test date
2. If the record.fieldid = 2 and record.fieldid <> 69
   compare the dates parameters.startdate with the date value from step 2 above,
   if the difference is LESS (earlier date only, not later date) then
   set the textcolor to Red
   otherwise set it to LimeGreen
3. If the record.fieldid wasn't 2 or the record.fieldid was 69 then
   we will use the color text value from step2
   otherwise set it to the default value (black?)

> ```
> ' Initialise
> Dim colorvalue As String
> Dim startdatevalue As Date
> Dim datedifvalue As Long
> colorvalue = Fields!def_Color.Value
> startdatevalue = New Date()
> datedifvalue = 0
>
> If Fields!FieldID.Value = 530 Then
>     ' The new code to be added
>     If datediff("d", Parameters!StartDate.Value, Fields!Value4Search) < 61 Then
>         If datediff("d", Fields!Value4Search, Parameters!StartDate.Value) > 31) Then
>             colorvalue = "DarkGreen"
>         Else
>             colorvalue = "Red"
>         End If
>     Else
>         colorvalue = "Red"
>     End If
> ElseIf (Fields!FieldTypeId.Value = 2) And (Fields!FieldID.Value <> 69) Then
>     ' The orginal code before addibng new code
>     If Fields!FieldTypeId.Value = 2 Then
>         startdatevalue = Cdate(FormatDateTime(Fields!Value4Search.Value), DateFormat.ShortDate)
>     Else
>         startdatevalue = Cdate(FormatDateTime(Parameters!StartDate.Value), DateFormat.ShortDate)
>     End If
>     colordifvalue = DateDiff("d", Parameters!StartDate.Value, startdatevalue)
>     If  colordifvalue < 0 Then
>         colorvalue = "Red"
>     Else
>         colorvalue = "LimeGreen"
>     End If
> Else
>     colorvalue = Fields!def_Color.Value
> End If
> ```

Comment: The OP's question relates to an SSRS expression, not VB. Your answer could be modified to be used by adding this as a custom function but until the OP explains what they are trying to achieve it's hard to tell what the best option is.

Comment: @Alan, Thank you I missed that. Ill leave whats posted since I don't know anything about SSRS, so I wouldn't know how to modify it.

Comment: No problem, if the OP ever updates the question and your answer is still useful I'll explain how it can be used in SSRS.